# Push notifications for iPhone

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I need to implement push notifications in my iPhone app. This is the first time I am working on this. I created certificates and a basic program. I need to link up with the server (the server is implemented in Java). I don't know how to link up. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple answer that'd fit in here. Read all the docs that apple provides.

This should help you out as well: http://www.easyapns.com/